# Sorting data from one excel sheet to several others

Tags: vba, excel

I am totally clueless when it comes to programming, hence am looking for some help here.

I have several worksheets in the book, each for a specific inventory item and a common one, which shows who the items went to. See example below:

**Common sheet**

```
Date |Code  |Name      |Reason|Item 1|Item 2|Item 3|Item 4|
1-may|ABC001|John Smith|Call  |1     |      |2     |1     |
2-may|CAA002|Mary Jane |New   |      |2     |2     |      |
```

**Item 1 sheet**

```
Date |Code  |Name      |Reason|Used|
1-may|ABC001|John Smith|Call  |1   |
```

What I need to do, is to populate individual items sheets from the main one on a daily basis. I.e. John will be entered in sheets with items 1,3 and 4 and Mary will be on items 2 and 3.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and got this mostly working, you may have to do some editing to make names of sheets match up with what they are in your workbook, also I am not entirely sure how you only copy certain columns (the code below will copy entire row)

```
Sub ConsolidateX()

Dim ws As Worksheet, wsItem1 As Worksheet, wsItem2 As Worksheet   'set ws"Name" to the sheet names in your workbook, define all worksheets that you are going to copy to
Dim lrow As Long, rng As Range
Dim tdate As Date

tdate = Date

Set wsItem1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Item 1")
Set wsItem2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Item 2")   'make sure you set all of your worksheet names for all of the items you wish to copy for

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

With ActiveSheet
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A2:I" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & tdate  'Leave this line in here to first filter for todays date (to prevent you from copying over old data
    .Range("A2:I" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" 'change the field # to reflect what column you are checking to make sure is not blank
    .Range("A3:I" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
    wsItem1.Range("A" & wsItem1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
.Range("A2:I" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & tdate   
.Range("A2:I" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>"  'just continue to copy this repeated part of code down for as many Items as you are trying to filter for remembering to change the Autofilter Field # and copy location
.Range("A3:I" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
wsItem2.Range("A" & wsItem2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

I tested this with a blank workbook and some dummy data so It should be okay so long as you change all the names and things to suit your workbook. 
Also make sure you run this Macro from your main sheet because it is only going to apply the filters and do the copying from the sheet you are currently on.

Sorry I am not sure how to copy the row like you intend but this should be a good starting point.